# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized, while accessing static property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have following code in a model that I have made to work with all DB related activities so I don’t get to write the redundant piece of code every time I want to work with the Database, this model class looks like this:

`Shared.cs`:

```
private static string ConStr
    {
        get
        {
            Shared shrObj = new Shared();
            return shrObj.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
        }

    }

    public static SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

    public static SqlDataReader ORC(SqlCommand sqlCom)
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlReader=null;
        
        try
        {
            SqlCon.Open();//ERROR HERE 
            //The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
            sqlReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToFile(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " | " + ex, 0);
            return sqlReader;
        }
        return sqlReader;
    }
            //Functions for closing connections…
            //Functions for reading scalar…
            //etc.
```

And now from other models when I try to use these function like this:
`User.cs`

```
internal IEnumerable<User> GetUser()
    {
        var sqlCom = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [user];", Shared.SqlCon);

        using (var blgs = Shared.ORC(sqlCom))
        {
            // ……. … …
            }
        }
    }
```

One more thing that confusing me is when this data read function is called for first time from here while logging in, it works fine it’s always the second time call which creates problem.

May be I am just not playing write with static properties. But I have to keep it static because it's being used by the `SqlConnection` object which itself is static to be used directly from outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a web app, it's usually better to open and close a connection via a using statement like so:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
     conn.Open();
// do some stuff
}
```

Don't reuse a sqlconnection as it can lead to unexpected timeouts in your webapp.